# When I read tags using beautifulsoup I always get None

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, tags

I'm trying to read some names and ids like:

```
<a class="inst" href="loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&amp;i=3823243780502959" 
target="3823243780502959">رتكو</a>

i = 3823243780502959
```

etc., from `tsetmc.com`. Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=15131F'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content , 'html.parser')
first_names_Id = soup.find_all('a',class_='isnt' )
print (first_names_Id)
```

but it returns `None`.

How can I read these tags? I have the same issue with other tags.

Answer (score 0):

I used Selenium instead of requests to access the website needed for parsing and it gave me the results you wanted.

I believe the reason why the requests library isn't returning the html response as the selenium library is because the website you want parse is rendered with JavaScript

Also note that you have a typo in the class attribute value, it should be 'inst' not 'isnt'.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=15131F'
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
first_names_Id = soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'inst'})
print(first_names_Id)
```

Output:

```
[<a class="inst" href="loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&amp;i=33541897671561960" target="33541897671561960">واتي</a>, <a class="inst" href="loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&amp;i=33541897671561960" target="33541897671561960">سرمايه‌ گذاري‌ آتيه‌ دماوند</a>, <a class="inst" href="loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&amp;i=9093654036027968" target="9093654036027968">طپنا7002</a>, <a class="inst" href="loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&amp;i=9093654036027968" target="9093654036027968">اختيارف رمپنا-7840-19/07/1396</a>, <a class="inst" href="loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&amp;i=19004627894176375" target="19004627894176375">طپنا7003</a>, <a class="inst" href="loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&amp;i=19004627894176375" target="19004627894176375">اختيارف رمپنا-8340-19/07/1396</a>, **etc**]
```